# Jquery show hide not working in ie7

Tags: php, jquery, html

Please refer this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qJBhD/4/

Here while clicking the question1, the answer1 is displayed.

But if we open this ie7, it is not working. Here while clicking the question1, the question2 is toggle.

How to fix this.

Comment: Well, for starters, that markup is invalid. List elements (ol and ul) must only contain li elements as their direct children.

Comment: @TiesonT. you are bang on :) didnt see your comments thats the answer ;)

Comment: @adeneo Despite your comment having quite a few points, it's a bit ignorant. There is nothing really implying that he would actually use ie7, just the opposite actually. But, even if he did, the point of writing code that supports ie7+ is to serve your customer/visitors with a properly functioning site.. Considering that this problem is not some small visual glitch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whole issue is because of your HTML markup.

use this

```
<div style="" id="25294" class="pane">

     <ol>
                         <li ><span class="question">Question 1 </span>  <p class="answer">
               Answer1</p>

              </li>

                         <li ><span class="question">Question 2</span> <p class="answer">
               Answer2
            </p>

              </li>

          <li ><span class="question">Question 3</span> <p class="answer">
               Answer3
            </p>

              </li>

         </ol></div>
```

Checked in IE7 (Compatibility mode works fine) - [updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qJBhD/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/qJBhD/12/)

Comment: If we use like this, the next question is toggled. I need the answer is only toggle.

Comment: $(this).next().slideToggle(); This is the code for toggle the answer. But it toggles the next li. I need this for next 'p' tag. For this i use the code like  $(this).next('p').slideToggle(); But it is not working

Comment: @designersvsoft Actually, he moved your question class to the span, so the next element is now the paragraph - this should work. EDIT: Yup, just verified it.

Comment: Oh. Sorry for that. I didn't notify that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

instead of this `<li class="question"><span></span></li><p class="answer"></p>` you should switch to `<li class="question"><span></span><p class="answer"></p></li>` 
and change your script to

```
$('p.answer').toggle();

$('.question').live('click', function() {
        $(this).children('p.answer').slideToggle();
        });​
```